# FFmpeg вставка видеофайла

Tags: ffmpeg

как в команду

> ffmpeg -i video.mpg image%d.jpg

```
вставить нужный видеоролик. Что я только не придумывал - ничего не получается
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужный видеоролик это входной файл - то так:

ffmpeg -i "имя_нужного_видеоролика" image%d.jpg - на выходе получите набор картинок. 
Если нужный видеоролик это выходной файл - то, например,так:

ffmpeg -i video.mpg -vcodec copy -acodec copy "имя_нужного_видеоролика"